# CFDocument doesn't respect custom margins

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

```
                marginBottom = "#arguments.topMargin#" 
                marginLeft = "#arguments.sideMargin#" 
                marginRight = "#arguments.sideMargin#" 
                marginTop = "#arguments.topMargin#"
```

I pass in custom margins of 0 yet a small gap is still left at top and side of pages. It is using the custom margins but not correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the document itself look like? What sort of CSS? body tag? etc.